# How to open vimwiki html page with a command in vim?

Tags: vim, vimwiki

I use gvim on Windows 10.I'd like to open wiki html page with command from a opened wiki page.
If I use the command ,
`:!start ..\Vimwiki_html\%:r.html`
it will translate to
`:!start ..\Vimwiki_html%:r.html`
The backslash is gone. My expectation is keep the baskslash charater and `%:r` will translate to a file name without extension.

If I use the command ,
`:!start ..\Vimwiki_html\"%:r".html`
it will translate to
`:!start ..\Vimwiki_html\"file name".html`
I don't want a pair double quotes.

Does anyone know what's the correct command? I can get the command string.
`:!start ..\Vimwiki_html\MyWiki.html`

Comment: `\\%:r` should do it.

Comment: I use the command `:silent !"%:r.html"`.  It can translate the file name and open html in the browser. Cool!